# Event Hub azure- sample in C - Receiver not working- Shows timeout

Tags: c, azure, azure-eventhub

I am beginner to azure event hub. I have tried the sample , [C sample from github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-c/blob/master/docs/desktop_ubuntu_setup.md).

I have successfully sent the messages, But receiveing it shows the error.

```
root@ala:~# ~/cmake/eventhub_client/samples/receive/receive
Info: Event Hubs Client SDK for C, version 0.10.0
Error: Time:Wed Apr 11 16:06:22 2018 File:/home/ala/azure-event-hubs/c/eventhub_client/src/eventhubreceiver_ll.c Func:HandleSASTokenAuth Line:277 EventHubAuthCBS Authentication Status Timed Out.

Error: Time:Wed Apr 11 16:06:22 2018 File:/home/ala/azure-event-hubs/c/eventhub_client/src/eventhubreceiver_ll.c Func:EventHubReceiver_LL_DoWork Line:1831 Authorization Timeout Observed

-> [CLOSE]* {}
ERROR: Unexpected Error Callback Triggered! 6
```

I have added the sharedaccesskey with event hub and also RootManageSharedAccessKey in event hub namespace. but both have same issue .

Please any one help me out from this. Thanks in advance